# In Firefox, is there any way to make Gmail Compose and Reply default to a separate window?

Tags: gmail

Is there any setting in Gmail, or any Firefox add-on or plug-in, that forces Gmail to always use full floating pop-out windows for both New Message Compose and Reply? The Firefox add-on "Old Compose" used to do this, but recent version updates to Firefox killed this plug-in several months ago and it no longer works. Also, the developer appears to have abandoned Old Compose, as there have been no updates for it in at least 18 months. The only way I have found to get pop-out floating reply windows in Gmail is to hold down the "shift" key when clicking the Reply, which pops-up a Reply screen as a "frame" which is still anchored to the Gmail window (not what I want!), then doing this AGAIN to force the "popped out" reply frame to actually un-anchor itself from the Gmail window, and become an independent window that I can move to the second monitor on a dual-monitor desktop system. This gets extremely aggravating after the umpteenth email I've replied to in a session. I ALWAYS want my email Reply and Compose windows to be fully-movable. I do not EVER want these windows to be anchored. Isn't there some way to make this the default? I don't want to have to keep doing a "shift and click" - TWICE! - to get a movable, floating Reply window.